# How to return a Bitmap from an Async Task in Android app

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-asynctask, imageview

Ok, so this code is right off the Android Developer site which sets an `ImageView` to a `Bitmap`:

```
class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, Bitmap> {
private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;
private int data = 0;

public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
    // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
    imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
}

// Decode image in background.
@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Integer... params) {
    data = params[0];
    return decodeSampledBitmapFromResource(getResources(), data, 100, 100));
}

// Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
    if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
        final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
        if (imageView != null) {
            imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }
}
}
```

And basically, what I want to do is instead of doing

`imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);` I want to return that `Bitmap` so I can then use it in my Main UI. Is there any way of going about doing this? Sorry about my lack of knowledge on `AsyncTask`, I just started learning it recently. Thank you!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Actually there is no need to return bitmap and than use it in main Ui Thread. You can do this on PostExecute becuase postExecute runs in UI Thread. Your question?? Yes you can return bitmap from AsynTask you can do something like this

```
private class myTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Bitmap>{


      protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

            //do stuff
             return bitmap;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {
            //do stuff

            }
        }
```

Now you can get bitmap by calling

```
 Bitmap returned_bitmap = new myTask().execute().get()
```

Again this is not good this will hang your UI. But you can get value from Aysnc like this.

**Another method you can do is by implementing callback using interface**

```
public interface MyInterface 
{
   public void onPostExecute();
}
```

Activity class

```
 public class MyActivity extends Activity implements MyInterface{

private Bitmap Image;

public void onCreate(Bundle b)
{
    super.onCreate(b);

    new MyTask(this).execute();
}

@Override
public void onPostExecute() {
        //Now you have your bitmap update by do in background 
    //do stuff here 
}


private class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>
{
    MyInterface myinterface;

    MyTask(MyInterface mi)
    {
        myinterface = mi;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        //firt declare bitmap as class member of MyActivity 
        //update bitmap here and then call

        myinterface.onPostExecute();

        return null;
    }

}

 }
```

Comment: I know that postExecute runs on the main thread, but I want to feed this bitmap into this adapter.add(new Location(BITMAP, "Place 1", "Description", "Distance", "Hours")); so if this adapter is declared in the main UI, how can I pass this into the adapter?

Comment: you can pass bitmap to adapter in postexecute() what's porblem with that?

Comment: Thank you, I just misunderstood how AsyncTask works, I think. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You should save yourself a lot of time and use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/). This will save you all of this code and it works with bitmaps. Basically you will write something like this:

```
Picasso.with(context).load("www.somthing.com/api/blah").placeholder(R.drawable.default_picture).into(imageView);
```

It's one line of code and you got Async and caching for free...

Comment: Picasso and Glide don't work with Map `setInfoWindowAdapter` when you need to download an image for every pin dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

You could either use a callback method through interface or put the asynctask as a inner class and just call the some method for setting the imageView...

For the callback there is a good example [here](http://android-er.blogspot.ca/2013/09/implement-callback-function-with.html).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, `onPostExecute` executes on your UI thread, so you don't need to do anything differently from the example.  But you can always use anonymous classes if you want:

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        AsyncTask task = new BitmapWorkerTask() {
            @Override
            public void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
                // Do whatever
            }
        };

        task.execute();
    }
}
```